# Getting history data for a specific date(YEAR AND MONTH) from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Consider the following employee_history table:

```
╔═════════╦═══════╦═════════════╦═══════════════╦══════╗
║ ID      ║ idEMP ║   startDate ║ endDate       ║ Money║
╠═════════╬═══════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬══════╣
║       1 ║ 1     ║ 2013-11-01  ║  2013-11-25   ║ 100  ║
║       2 ║ 1     ║ 2013-11-25  ║  2014-01-01   ║ 50   ║
║       3 ║ 1     ║ 2014-01-01  ║  2014-01-10   ║ 25   ║
║       4 ║ 1     ║ 2014-01-10  ║  2014-01-15   ║ 50   ║
║       5 ║ 1     ║ 2014-01-15  ║  2014-01-20   ║ 18   ║
║       6 ║ 1     ║ 2014-01-20  ║  2014-02-01   ║ 70   ║
║       7 ║ 1     ║ 2014-02-01  ║    NULL       ║ 10   ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

*Basically , it means that from startDate to endDate the employee has the amount of 'Money'.*

What I need to do is to find for an employee in the **history table** all the records for a specific **YEAR and MONTH.** But without getting records which are ending in the first day of the next month.

For example : If I'd search for '2013-12-01' this should be the output:

```
   ╔═════════╦═══════╦═════════════╦═══════════════╦══════╗
   ║ ID      ║ idEMP ║   startDate ║ endDate       ║ Money║
   ╠═════════╬═══════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬══════╣
   ║       2 ║ 1     ║ 2013-11-25  ║  2014-01-01   ║ 50   ║
```

If I'd search for '2013-11-01' the output would be :

```
   ╔═════════╦═══════╦═════════════╦═══════════════╦══════╗
   ║ ID      ║ idEMP ║   startDate ║ endDate       ║ Money║
   ╠═════════╬═══════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬══════╣
   ║       1 ║ 1     ║ 2013-11-01  ║  2013-11-25   ║ 100  ║
   ║       2 ║ 1     ║ 2013-11-25  ║  2014-01-01   ║ 50   ║
```

If I'd search for '2014-01-1' the output would be :

```
   ╔═════════╦═══════╦═════════════╦═══════════════╦══════╗
   ║ ID      ║ idEMP ║   startDate ║ endDate       ║ Money║
   ╠═════════╬═══════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬══════╣
   ║       3 ║ 1     ║ 2014-01-01  ║  2014-01-10   ║ 25   ║
   ║       4 ║ 1     ║ 2014-01-10  ║  2014-01-15   ║ 50   ║
   ║       5 ║ 1     ║ 2014-01-15  ║  2014-01-20   ║ 18   ║
   ║       6 ║ 1     ║ 2014-01-20  ║  2014-02-01   ║ 70   ║
```

If I'd search for '2014-05-01' the output would be:

```
   ╔═════════╦═══════╦═════════════╦═══════════════╦══════╗
   ║ ID      ║ idEMP ║   startDate ║ endDate       ║ Money║
   ╠═════════╬═══════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬══════╣
   ║       7 ║ 1     ║ 2014-02-01  ║    NULL       ║ 10   ║
```

I've tried all I've got in my mind and also googled a little bit more but I couldn't find a way of making the proper query for this.

Could someone help me ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: where datevalue between startdate and enddate?

Comment: I don't see how the limiting date applies to the sets, please explain. For instance, why does date `'2014-01-1'` return ids `4, 5, 6`?

Comment: @Jodrell - I'm sorry I forgot to mention it. The search is supposed to be done by YEAR and MONTH . So , the day doesn't matter . It just needs all the rows for the specified year and month.

Comment: I'm assuming its possible for start and end to be more than a month apart?

Comment: Shouldn't your results for `2014-01-01` include ID 2?

Comment: @Jchao - That's the issue . It shouldn't because ID 2 Ends in the month in which I'm searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sth like this should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee_history
WHERE startDate <= DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@searchDate)+1,0)) AND
      (endDate > CAST(CAST(YEAR(@searchDate) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(MONTH(@searchDate) AS varchar) + '-01' AS DATETIME)
      OR endDate is null)
```

The following expresion:

```
DECLARE @searchDate DATE = '2013-11-01'
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@searchDate)+1,0))
```

yields this output:

```
2013-11-30 23:59:59.000
```

i.e. the *last day* of the month of the 'search date'.

Whereas, this expression:

```
DECLARE @searchDate DATE = '2013-11-01'
SELECT CAST(CAST(YEAR(@searchDate) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(MONTH(@searchDate) AS varchar) + '-01' AS DATETIME)
```

yields the *first day* of the month of the 'search date'.

Thus said, the query I propose fetches all records whose intervals, i.e. `startDate` - `endDate`, *overlap* with the month that corresponds to the 'search date'.

Comment: I'll try your solution when I get  home because I left from work. Hope it may work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT money, startdate, substring_index(startdate,'-','-1') as date
FROM table
WHERE date = '2014-01'
```

the following code sorts it by month
try this, I kinda of deciphered what you meant. 
I assume this is what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

try somthing like that:

```
select ID,
idEMP,
rtrim(startDate || ' ' || endDate) as empl_time,
Money 
from employee_history
where empl_time like '%<your values>%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Search date you're entering must be varchar as yyyy-mm then the following should work:

```
Select *
from tbl
where @date between Cast(startDate as varchar(7)) and Cast(DateAdd(Month, -1, ISNULL(endDate, '9999-12-31')) as varchar(7))
```

@date - being your 'yyyy-mm' varchar

Comment: I've done that befor adding this question . The problem is that it also returns the record wich ends in that Month . For example : by using '2014-01-01' I'd shouldn't get the row with ID 2

Comment: That's a bit confusing but the above should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *
from Table1
where Cast(startDate as varchar(7)) <= Cast('YOUR_DATE'as varchar(7))
and (Cast(startDate as varchar(7)) > Cast('YOUR_DATE'as varchar(7))
     or Cast(startDate as varchar(7)) is null);
```

You can also check this demo in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a12f/1).

EDIT: removed =

Comment: 've done that befor adding this question . The problem is that it also returns the record wich ends in that Month . For example : by using '2014-01-01' I'd shouldn't get the row with ID 2

Comment: what about if you use just `enddate > 'YOUR_DATE'` instead of `enddate >= 'YOUR_DATE'`. This won't return ID 2